# Advantages and disadvantages to using @Before over a test class constructor?

Tags: java, junit

*Question*: Are there advantages to using a setup method annotated with `@Before` over using a test class' constructor in JUnit 4.  If not, why is using the `@Before` annotation so common?

*Rationale for Asking:*
In JUnit it's standard practice to use a method annotated with `@Before` to initialize objects shared across tests:

```
public class TestFoo {
    private TestObject testObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //setup testObject
    }

    @Test
    public void testBar() {
        assert...("Some assertion", testObject.bar(), ...);
    }
}
```

The behavior of @Before is it is called before each test.  However, as the test type is instantiated before each @Test this is no different than using the constructor:

```
public class TestFoo {
    private final TestObject testObject;
    public TestFoo() {
        //setup testObject
    }

    @Test
    public void testBar() {
        assert...("Some assertion", testObject.bar(), ...);
    }
}
```

Using the constructor has the added benefit of being able to make any instance variables of TestFoo `final`!

So it seems that using the test class' constructor potentially has an advantage over a set-up method annotated with `@Before`.

Comment: You can have multiple test functions in your test class, no?  The constructor is only called once.  Also consider that error "reporting" is very different in each of those places - @Before is not a test, and assumed to not throw any exceptions for purposes of the test framework process...

Comment: (you can throw exceptions in each to see the differences in what happens in situ in your env)

Comment: @BadZen JUnit instantiates a class for _each_ test method. So the constructor is called as often as test methods exist.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose   Ah, good to know, if true I was mistaken about that.   I definitely thought I'd shared some class fields between tests before, however.  Hm.  Maybe they were actually static vars.